# GatsbyJS: How do I load a component synchronously at build time, but asynchronously at runtime?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have a Gatsby site with a React component called `ArticleBody` that uses [react-markdown](https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown) to convert an article written in Markdown to a React tree.

As this is a bit of an expensive operation and a somewhat large component — and for SEO reasons — I'd like to pre-render `ArticleBody` at build time. However, I'd also like to load `ArticleBody` *asynchronously* in the client. Since the article body will already be included in the HTML, there's no rush to load and render the Markdown component in the client, so async should be fine.

How would I accomplish this? It's almost as if I want to have two different JS bundles — one bundle that loads `ArticleBody` synchronously, for the build, and one that loads it asynchronously, for the client. Is this possible in Gatsby?

Thanks!

Comment: I am a bit confused. I thought the whole point of Gatsby was to use your components and generate static html pages out of it... so, if you have 4 articles, you will get 4 pages of html after you do `gatsby build`. Once rendered as html, the performance hit would barely be noticeable. Can you elaborate a bit on how you are serving/hosting your app?

Comment: @dubes correct, it generates 4 pages for 4 articles. However, the 4 HTML pages also include JavaScript bundles for "hydrating" the pages. What I'd like to do is make sure that, when the hydration process runs, the `ArticleBody` component is loaded asynchronously. This is for performance reasons — it allows the browser to do other important work on the main thread if it needs to, rather than rushing to render `ArticleBody` (since the HTML from `ArticleBody` is already on the page). Does that make sense?

Comment: Does make sense... I think [`React.lazy`](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) with `suspense` should work, but I am not familiar with what goes on with Gatsby build to be sure.

Comment: Unfortunately, Gatsby doesn't currently support `React.lazy` and `React.Suspense`. But even if it did, that wouldn't solve the issue, as I basically want to use `React.lazy` in the client, but load the component synchronously at build time.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of React.lazy which is not supported, you can use loadable components. There is a Gatsby plugin to handle SSR correctly [gatsby-plugin-loadable-components-ssr](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-loadable-components-ssr/)

Currently there is an issue with it since Gatsby 3.x, but there is a way to implement it yourself without the extra plugin. See the comment in the issue [here](https://github.com/hector-del-rio/gatsby-plugin-loadable-components-ssr/issues/12#issuecomment-811117554). Also add the changes mentioned in the comment below of it.

I haven't tried this specific implementation yet, but it should work with the following steps:

```
npm install --save-dev @loadable/babel-plugin @loadable/server @loadable/webpack-plugin @loadable/component
```

**gatsby-browser.js**

```
import { loadableReady } from '@loadable/component'
import { hydrate } from 'react-dom'

export const replaceHydrateFunction = () => (element, container, callback) => {
  loadableReady(() => {
    hydrate(element, container, callback)
  })
}
```

**gatsby-node.js**

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions, stage }) => {
  if (
    stage === "build-javascript" ||
    stage === "develop" ||
    stage === "develop-html"
  ) {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      plugins: [
        new LoadablePlugin({
          filename:
            stage === "develop"
              ? `public/loadable-stats.json`
              : "loadable-stats.json",
          writeToDisk: true
        })
      ]
    });
  }
};
```

**gatsby-ssr.js**

```
import { ChunkExtractor } from '@loadable/server'
import path from 'path'

const extractor = new ChunkExtractor({
  // Read the stats file generated by webpack loadable plugin.
  statsFile: path.resolve('./public/loadable-stats.json'),
  entrypoints: [],
})

// extractor.collectChunks() will wrap the application in a ChunkExtractorManager
export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) =>
  extractor.collectChunks(element)

export const onRenderBody = ({ setHeadComponents, setPostBodyComponents }) => {
  // Set link rel="preload" tags in the head to start the request asap. This will NOT parse the assets fetched
  setHeadComponents(extractor.getLinkElements())

  // Set script and style tags at the end of the document to parse the assets.
  setPostBodyComponents([...extractor.getScriptElements(), ...extractor.getStyleElements()])

  // Reset collected chunks after each page is rendered
  extractor.chunks = []
}
```

If you have DEV_SSR enabled, you should not add stage === "develop-html". Otherwise, you are good.

Hope this summary of the issue's comments help to get you started.

Comment: In `onRenderBody` where do the `setHeadComponents` and `setPostBodyComponents` functions come from?

Comment: @alxndr Thanks for pointing it out. I edited the answer and included the functions in the parameters as mentioned in this doc: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-ssr/#onRenderBody